# Idiomatic Scala for handling concurrency in a web application

Tags: scala, concurrency

I need to build a rudimentary RESTful session management service in Scala. A user will login and receive a session id in return. This session id will be validated on each service call. Users will be logged out after a period of inactivity.

The session management service will (could) be a simple in-memory singleton, with a map of session ids to expiry times. Where a user's session has expired it should be removed from the map. The map can be read and written by multiple threads simultaneously.

Idiomatic Scala would suggest this map be immutable but how would I handle updates? As I see the options:

- Synchronize access to a mutable map
- Make the map immutable but synchronize access to its reference

What is the idiomatic way of handling this kind of problem?

Note: Akka is **not** an option, but other libraries are.

Comment: Are there available libraries/frameworks also out of scope? e.g. Play!, Finagle or even Spray?

Comment: Finagle is an option yes - how can it help me here?

Answer (score 1):

As a developer, you have a set of techniques to deal with concurrency that you can pick up. If you decide to go for synchronisation, you should be aware of the price:

- Performance decreases as lock contention increase
- Lock contention is a function of how long locks are held
- You need to fine tune locking (or you'll end up in the degenerate case where the lock is held forever -> single threading)

Using a singleton with synchronized access makes latency increase very quickly. Assuming each request keeps the lock for 30ms, and requests arrive every 25ms, you will have a growing latency and your users will be really upset.

If your application is a trivial exercise, go for locking. If your application has speed/latency requirement, the sooner you abandon synchronization techniques the better. And by the way, storing session in memory won't work if you need to deploy your application in a highly available cluster.

Comment: Ok good point, thank you. So what other options do I have for handling this without synchronisation? (I don't have to move to a cluster - yet - this is a semi-tactical solution).